# Debugging Unattended Installer, ua-netinst, RPi3Bv1.2

Tags: boot, pi-3, ethernet, software-installation, boot-issues

I'm attempting to install [`un-netinst`](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst) using the instructions [here](https://github.com/EthEmbedded/Raspi-Eth-Install). My ultimate aim is to install an 
[Ethereum Client](http://ethembedded.com/).

I have reformatted my 64GB SD disk to FAT32 and copied the files as instructed (using Windows7 and [Macroit Partition Manager](http://macrorit.com/download.html)):

[image: SD card setup for EthEmbedded]

*Link: http://ethembedded.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ua-netinst-sd-card-list.png*

When I power up the Pi (3 Model B V1.2), the power LED comes on but nothing else happens.

I get no signal to the monitor.

**What steps should I take to debug this?**

The [install config file](https://github.com/EthEmbedded/Raspi-Eth-Install/releases/) is as below:

```
preset=server
packages=sudo,nano,screen,dphys-swapfile,git,unzip # comma separated list of extra packages
mirror=http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/
release=jessie
hostname=ethpi
domainname=
rootpw=root
cdebootstrap_cmdline=
bootsize=+128M # /boot partition size as given to fdisk
rootsize=     # / partition size in megabytes, leave empty to use all free space
timeserver=time.nist.gov
ip_addr=dhcp
ip_netmask=0.0.0.0
ip_broadcast=0.0.0.0
ip_gateway=0.0.0.0
ip_nameservers=
online_config= # URL to extra config that will be executed after installer-config.txt
usbroot= # set to 1 to install to first USB disk
cmdline="dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 elevator=deadline"
rootfstype=ext4
rootfs_mkfs_options=
rootfs_install_mount_options='noatime,data=writeback,nobarrier,noinit_itable'
rootfs_mount_options='errors=remount-ro,noatime'
```

My initial thoughts are that the FAT32 formatting is somehow incorrect. Windows indicates that the card is FAT32 formatted (RightClick->Properties). Is this enough to confirm that the format is correct?

**EDIT:**

I've also tried the following [suggested by GitHub user 4eMaLo](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/issues/375#issuecomment-218224377):

> I got it to work for me by copying the boot/ directory from the
>   official reposiory into the SD root and adding
>
> [pi3] 
>   initramfs installer-rpi2.cpio.gz
>
> to config.txt

Unfortunately I still get no response, aside from power on LED, from the Pi however.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst/issues/375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the SD Card was not correctly formatted to FAT32. The Window7 "properties" dialogue box did show it as FAT 32.

I changed formatting tools and managed to get it working - [although not completely](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50834/edit-fat16-microsd-disk-partition).

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.